# Is there a BASIC compiler for Ubuntu which will run a program written in 1984 for the TRS-80 computer?

Tags: compiler

I'm copying a BASIC program from a book written in 1984 and want a compiler to run it on in Ubuntu. I'm not a coder so I don't have the skills to modify the code to  a different version of BASIC than the version used in the book.

Comment: You'll probably need to be more specific than you have been, there was Level I basic for the TRS-80, then later Level II which was not compatible with Level I basic. Chances are you mean Level II (which is mostly equivalent to DOS basic except for how it moves cursor around the screen  [`print@` vs `locate` or something like that]) but currently which TRS-80 basic hasn't been provided.

Comment: FYI: If you're talking about Tandy/Radio Shack Level I basic (which was highly efficient, but also different to other BASIC languages) you'll likely have little chance. As stated in prior comment, Level II basic for the TRS-80 was written by Microsoft, thus is very like any other CP/M, MS-DOS, PC-DOS BASIC written by Microsoft on the whole (exception being moving the cursor around; missing sound or beep opcodes but they weren't in CP/M versions either; being added later in MS-DOS)